# Proguard issues with Roboguice 3

Tags: android, proguard, roboguice

I'm trying to import Roboguice but when I do I get a bunch of Proguard errors.

I have looked at the other questions but none of the answers seem to work for me. I am trying to import Roboguice 3 to use the Coinbase Android SDK which looks to be required. It seems to be looking for the sherlock libraries which i dont use.

My gradle error is long so it can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/w3sT45y9).

My Proguard is:

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump ../bin/class_files.txt
-printseeds ../bin/seeds.txt
-printusage ../bin/unused.txt
-printmapping ../bin/mapping.txt

# The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle.
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep class com.google.inject.Binder
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
# There's no way to keep all @Observes methods, so use the On*Event convention to identify event handlers
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(**On*Event);
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
-keep public class roboguice.**
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.internal.**
-dontwarn robojuice.activity.**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the final warnings go away so it will complete the compile:

```
-dontwarn roboguice.**
-dontwarn org.roboguice.**
```

However, this only works if it truly doesn't need that library (and the other classes it mentions in the `Warning:` lines) and doesn't try loading it. If it does try at runtime, it will crash.

As always, **TEST ALL CODE PATHS** since it is common for dependency injection errors to show up at runtime, especially when using ProGuard.